# Can I allow a compiled Deno executable to access a single hostname provided at runtime?

Tags: deno

I have a service that makes network requests to an external backing service. The requests use TLS, so I can't use any kind of hostname aliasing, and there are different hostnames for development and production environments.

I know that I can use `deno package` to bundle my application into a single runnable `app.js` and then have my container command be

```
deno run --allow-net=${BACKING_SERVICE_HOSTNAME} app.js
```

However, it would be nice to be able to use `deno compile` to produce a runnable binary. For that, permissions must be provided at **build** time, so am I stuck either allowing my app to make all network calls (`--allow-net`) or providing all the hostnames that development and production deployments might need at once? Or is there a way to allow network calls to only one host, but provide that host at runtime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Right now there is no way to downgrade the permissions of a program using the current permissions API

A request for such feature was made due to this conversation, so that might change in the near future

Comment: Please do. I haven't seen an example of adding permissions at runtime that don't require an interactive session.

Comment: @MSmedberg After some investigation, I discovered that wildcard permissions can be revoked after the start of the program, however there is no way of doing so and keeping some specific hosts, rendering your program basically unable to make any requests

I edited my answer to reflect that, however that may become possible in the future